# having handle to a menu (HMENU) is it possible to find it's parent window (HWND)?

Tags: winapi, menu, window

I know about the option for system menu, that is the alt+space one. And it's not pretty it involves looping all open windows through `GetNextWindow`. But I want to ask in more general way. That is having any menu handle, not necessarily to system menu (that is easy to find for any window) is it possible to get to its parent window ?

Comment: You loop through the windows and call GetMenu().  Kinda bizarre to have a HMENU and not having any idea where it came from btw.

Comment: I have a function that does something tothe menu I do not own, and I thought that it may figure it's hwnd without passing another argument.

Comment: Do not do things to menus you do not own. That's just rude.

Answer (score 4):

No.  Menus can be shared across windows, so there's no unique mapping from menus to windows.

Answer (score 4):

In the particular case when hmenu obtained on the fly from an existing menu-window (class #32768): 
you can use GUITHREADINFO.hwndMenuOwner via GetGUIThreadInfo(GetWindowThreadProcessId). 
"On the fly" means: via SendMessageTimeout(MN_GETHMENU) or via GetMenuBarInfo(OBJID_CLIENT), after WindowFromPoint.